# Isto é uma gambiarra?

Tags: python, estilo-de-codificação

Estou começando na programação, tenho certa dificuldade em ler códigos até mesmo os meus depois de um tempo.

fui da uma pesquisada sobre legibilidade e me deparei com o termo "gambiarra". isso me levantou uma questão.

o que exatamente define uma gambiarra e como evitar criar uma?

códigos como esse no qual eu estava escrevendo e acabei me perdendo podem ser considerados gambiarras?

```
class Skeleton:
def __init__(self, names_list, delimiters=",. /*"):
    self.deimiters = [char for char in delimiters]
    self.__items = {}

    for name in names_list:
        replaced_name = name
        for delimiter_char in self.deimiters:
            replaced_name = replaced_name.replace(delimiter_char, " ")
        tokens = replaced_name.split()
        for i in range(len(tokens)):
            key = " ".join(tokens[:i + 1])
            if key in self.__items:
                item = self.__items[key]
                if name not in item["shapes"]:
                    item["shapes"].append(name)
            else:
                self.__items[key] = {}
                item = self.__items[key]
                item["shapes"] = []
                item["shapes"].append(name)
```

Comment: Algo em específico?

Comment: Gambiarra == solução inadequada (de difícil manutenção ou de alto custo) que resolve o problema em curto prazo.

Comment: Na minha opinião o conceito de gambiarra é muito relativo, gambiarra não tem a ver legibilidade, vc pode fazer uma gambiarra altamente legivel, eheheh! Gambiarra é qdo vc escolhe um caminho, mesmo que duvidoso ou arriscado, somente pq vai te dar um resultado mais rápido e vai resolver o problema no prazo imediato. Por ex. vc faz um "webscraping" em um site, mesmo tendo uma API disponível, só pq considera que trabalhar com a API vai demandar mais tempo e trabalho.

Comment: Mas as vezes vc é quase que obrigado a fazer a gambiarra, considere que vc não esteja encontrando a API que atenda o que vc precisa. Posso citar como exemplo [o caso no nosso colega Gabriel.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/211322/atualizar-valores-de-um-gr%C3%A1fico-usando-django/211378#211378)

Comment: Humm, então seria uma solução não tão eficiente ou extensível quanto deveria ser mas que é rápida de escrever..

Comment: Referência em gambiarras: [Gambi Design Patterns](http://desciclopedia.org/wiki/Gambi_Design_Patterns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gambiarra pode ter várias interpretações, mas nunca é a melhor solução definitiva. Pode ser algo provisório, mas não permanente.

Se tratando de Python, acho que a filosofia dele é um ótimo ponto de partida para entender o que talvez seja uma gambiarra e como fazer um ótimo código:

> Belo é melhor que feio.
>  Explícito é melhor que implícito.
>     Simples é melhor que complexo.
>  Complexo é melhor que    complicado.
>  Plano é melhor que aninhado.
>  Esparso é melhor que    denso.
>  Legibilidade conta.
>  Casos especiais não são especiais    o suficiente para violar as regras.
>  Embora praticidade vença    pureza.
>  Erros não devem passar silenciosamente.
>  A não ser que    sejam explicitamente silenciados.
>  Em caso de ambiguidade, resista    à tentação de adivinhar.
>  Deve haver um - e somente um - jeito    óbvio de fazer.
>  Embora tal jeito não seja tão óbvio no à primeira    vista a não ser que você seja holandês.
>  Agora é melhor que    nunca.
>  Embora nunca é frequentemente melhor que exatamente    agora.
>  Se a implementação é difícil de explicar, a ideia é    ruim.
>  Se a implementação é fácil de explicar, talvez a ideia seja    boa.
>  Espaços de nomes são uma ideia estupenda - vamos fazer mais    deles!

Comment: já tinha lido isso mas não pensei nessa possibilidade.